# Killing shell using terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash

```
echo $$
```

It tells the PID of the shell. So, if I kill this shell using

```
kill 123 #suppose 123 is PID of shell
```

Nothing happens actually, I tried it. 
I again ran

```
echo $$
```

and the shell was running under same PID.
Why the shell is not stopped ? 
What  may happen if the shell is killed ?

Comment: You are not killing the shell, you'd be killing the "terminal window." You can kill terminal A from terminal B, though.

Comment: Can a terminal kill itself by this way ?

Comment: Why not just press Ctrl+D (which sends EOF)?

Comment: @m.becerra pid of window is different from what shell pid is, which is what $$ is supposed to show

Comment: This works: `kill -9 $$`

Comment: that really worked, what is the role of -9 here?

Comment: It sends a SIGKILL signal (instant obliteration) instead of SIGTERM (a friendly "hey, please shut down") to the process. It seems that bash simply catches SIGTERM (whereas SIGKILL is uncatchable).

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is because shells are built to trap the `TERM` signal. This behavior is documented. To quote bash 4.3 manual:

> SIGNALS
>
> When bash is interactive, in the absence of any traps, it ignores SIGTERM (so that kill  0  does  not  kill  an
>          interactive  shell),  and  SIGINT  is  caught  and handled (so that the wait builtin is interruptible).  In all
>          cases, bash ignores SIGQUIT.  If job control is in effect, bash ignores SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU, and SIGTSTP.

From `man kill`:

> The  default signal for kill is TERM.

Now if you were to specify `kill -KILL $$`, what would indeed kill your shell, and once the controlling shell exits - that would close the terminal. The options `-9`, `-KILL` and `-SIGKILL` are all aliases for the same `kill` signal, which is why any of these 3 work, and is one of the aliases that Siguza pointed out in the comments.

Contrasting to what M. Becerra said, this has nothing to do with window itself, as window PID is always different from shell's:

```
# Shell PID
$ cat /proc/self/status  | grep '^Pid:'                                                                                  
Pid:    7058
$ echo $$                                                                                                                
14709
# GUI window PID
$ xdotool getactivewindow getwindowpid 
2774
```